# Firefox navigator get blocked because navigator.appName does not contains "Microsoft Internet Explorer", how to hack this?

Tags: firefox, w3c

A stupid application blocks my Firefox navigator because navigator.appName does not contains "Microsoft Internet Explorer".

I want the javacsript code `navigator.appName` to retrun something containing  `Microsoft Internet Explorer` instead of the w3c standard `Netscape`.

The option `general.useragent.override` does not change the answers and have some border effects.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new string preference named `general.appname.override` in [about:config](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox#w_opening-aboutconfig) and set it to the value you want (here's the [source code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/cf149b7b63ff97023e28723167725e38cf5df757/dom/base/Navigator.cpp#1782) that uses it).